# SQL Server using triggers and geting rid of ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, cascade

I have 2 tables, A and B.

Table B has a foreign key pointing to primary key of table A. The foreign key on table B has ON DELETE CASCADE, so the corresponding records from B is deleted when a record from A is deleted.

My requirement is to track all added/updated/deleted records in history tables. I have trigger on each table to insert the records into history tables(AHistories and BHistories tables).

I do not like the order ON DELETE CASCADE deletes the records. Trigger A is executed after trigger B, so I have to work around to get the ID of AHistory into BHistory record.

I am wanting to get rid of ON DELETE CASCADE and perform Delete on the records of B in trigger A then insert the deleted record of B into BHistories there.

To demonstrate the idea, I made the case simple, but I have a few more tables that have a foreign key pointing to the primary key in table A. Personally, I would like if I can specify the order and what I do on delete cascade.

Does this stink as an approach? Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: but you may have no choice....

Comment: SQL Enterprise required, but Change Data Capture could be a nice option for you. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: The other option is to disallow delete and handle the logic in a stored proc. Worthwhile if you have users able to use a program like Microsoft Access.

Comment: @GaryWalker Thanks for the suggestion. At least at this moment, I don't have access to SQL Enterprise and still might not in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bad as triggers are but sometimes they are the only way to implement complex business requirements. I would do something as follows in the following example `PK_ID` refers to `Primary Key Column`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Table_A_InsteadOfDelete
ON dbo.TableA
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- Insert into History Table from TableB

    INSERT INTO TABLE_B_History
    SELECT B.*
    FROM TableB B INNER JOIN deleted d
    ON B.PK_ID = d.PK_ID

    -- Delete rows from TableB

      DELETE FROM TableB
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM deleted 
                      WHERE PK_ID = TableB.PK_ID) 

    -- Insert into History Table from TableA

    INSERT INTO TABLE_A_History
    SELECT A.*
    FROM TableA A INNER JOIN deleted d
    ON A.PK_ID = d.PK_ID

    -- Delete rows from TableA

      DELETE FROM TableA
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM deleted 
                      WHERE PK_ID = TableA.PK_ID) 

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END
```

Comment: Could you explain what `INNER JOIN` does for you? Assuming Deleted is always a single record, how is it different from doing `INSERT INTO TABLE_B_HISTORY SELECT B.* FROM TABLEB WHERE B.FK = (SELECT ID FROM Deleted)`?

Comment: This assumption that always only One record will be deleted at a time, is very much error prone. This inner join will handle multiple deletions nicely.

Comment: When you say multiple records, does one trigger execution take a batch of all records updated at that time at once? Or is it a batch per user operation? What I'm trying to ask is, do I need to worry about one trigger execution handling multiple records update from multiple users?

Comment: @awonderer One Delete statement will be wrapped in a batch, This trigger will fire for each delete statement issued against TableA, whether deleting multiple rows or single row. I have wrapped all the Deletions from TableA and TableB also Inserts in both history table in ONE transaction. this will make sure no orphan records are left in any of the four tables.

Comment: I see. One difference I have from the example is that I want to set a foreign key value in B_History records to point to a primary key in A_History. So I need to get the id of A_History before I insert deleted B into B_History. How would I accommodate this from your example?

Comment: This is simple, Inside this transaction just change the order of operations. Insert into HistoryA first then HistoryB and then do the deletions, from tableA and then TableB, Sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

Using triggers for audit purposes is as obvious as it's wrong. If you have sufficient permissions, they can be disabled too easily.

Nevertheless, what you want to do can be achieved with the combination of:

1. INSTEAD OF DELETE triggers, where you can delete or move rows around in any order;
2. Disabling nested triggers. This might has unpleasant side effects, if you use triggers for more than just the audit, because it's a database-wide option.

Just don't forget that in such a trigger, you have to manually delete rows from its underlying table, as well.

Comment: I don't understand. You say that triggers solve the problem but are "wrong". So what solves the problem and is right?

Comment: @dumbledad, triggers solve only part of the problem. Their main drawback is that they can be disabled relatively easily, leaving no traces of who did it. Another problem is that since they are never called directly, people eventually forget about them, and newly developed features start to clash with triggers' logic. For audit alone, CDC or change tracking can be more robust and / or reliable. They are also more transparent from the SQL developers perspective.