# SQL Server : how do I prevent a record from being deleted if one of its columns is equal to a certain value

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-2016

Let us say that I have a straightforward master - detail relation between two tables (`OrderHeaders` and `OrderDetails` for example). If I want to allow detail records to be deleted at the same time as a master record is deleted, I can set the delete action on the relationship between the two to cascade.

This is fine is the tables are essentially independent of anything else in the database. However if we were to turn an order into an invoice at some point, then quite clearly one wouldn't want to delete an order or its related details.

In my equivalent of the `OrderHeaders` table I added a simple boolean column (`Posted`) that is set to true if an order has been converted to an invoice.

What is the correct way in SQL to impose a rule on the `OrderHeaders` table to prevent the deletion of a record if the value of `Posted` is equal to true?

If there are in fact better approaches to this particular situation then I'm perfectly open to suggestions, it's always good to learn something new.

Comment: If I understand it right, you wish to delete from Details when there is delete in the OrderHeaders, but that should be conditional based on Posted flag which is in another table?

Comment: Is anything else stored when an order is converted to an invoice? If so, could that not have a FK to the OrderHeaders instead of the Posted column, and have that FK not cascade?

Comment: @Sujith  The Posted field is in the OrderHeaders table itself.

Comment: @DomSinclair, as there is no conditional cascading deletes, your options are either a `DELETE` trigger (which I don't like AT ALL), or ensure that your deletes happen through a stored procedure (which IMHO always should be the case).

Answer (score 0):

There are no conditional CASCADE. To handle the conditional delete just define a trigger to delete child rows manually. (see the [SQL Server using triggers and geting rid of ON DELETE CASCADE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221925/sql-server-using-triggers-and-geting-rid-of-on-delete-cascade))

Comment: I was rather afraid that that might be the case.  Personally I dislike cascade delete as it's far too easy to do something you later regret.  In this case therefore my best approach might be to filter records in the UI based on the posted value and either enable or disable the delete button accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating an invoice? I can tell you that SAP, for instance, simply copies the order header and all it's details to invoice and invoice details, so you can do whatever you want to the order but the invoice stays the same. Personally, I don't think that's a good solution, since it's basically keeping the same data twice (actually, if I remember correctly, it's ever worst in sap - the data is being duplicated 2, 3, 4 and maybe even 5 times).

One fairly simple solution would be to add connect the invoice to the order details table with a foreign key that's not cascading deletes. this way, when you create the invoice, you link it to the order details. Once a record can't be deleted from the order details table, it's parent record can't be deleted from the orders table.

I've made up a simple demo on [rextester](http://rextester.com/UJKQ5705) to show you what I mean - here is the complete example (in case rextester is unavailable):

```
CREATE TABLE OrderHeader
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    createDate datetime
);

CREATE TABLE Invoice
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    createDate datetime,
    OrderId int foreign key references OrderHeader(id)
);

CREATE TABLE OrderDetails
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    orderId int foreign key references OrderHeader(id) on delete cascade,
    itemId int,
    invoiceId int NULL foreign key references Invoice(id)
);


INSERT INTO OrderHeader (createDate) VALUES (DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())), (GETDATE());

INSERT INTO OrderDetails (orderId, itemId) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2);

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO Invoice (createDate, OrderId) VALUES (GETDATE(), 1) ;

UPDATE OrderDetails 
SET invoiceId = scope_identity()
WHERE OrderId = 1;

COMMIT TRANSACTION

SELECT 'Headers', * FROM OrderHeader;
SELECT 'Details', * FROM OrderDetails;
SELECT 'Invoice', * FROM Invoice;

DELETE FROM OrderHeader WHERE Id = 2;

SELECT 'Headers', * FROM OrderHeader;
SELECT 'Details', * FROM OrderDetails;
SELECT 'Invoice', * FROM Invoice;

DELETE FROM OrderHeader WHERE Id = 1;
```